# how to unfold a tuple but still keep the elemnts near to each other?

Tags: julia

I have a long list of tuples, containing a set of corrdinates in a forms of `(lat,long)` and it stored as `250000-element Vector{Tuple{Float64, Float64}}:`

Now I'd like to call some of the functions in Opernsteetmap.jl package on these tuples. But the issue is that the function doesn't accept the tuple, it jsu t need to lat and lon to be near to each other. That is if you have a tuple a = (39.5299, -119.8143) and you want to call `LLA` command on it, it returns an error if you call `nearest_node(map, ENU(a), map.bounds))` instead you should do:

`nearest_node(map, ENU(LLA(39.5299, -119.8143), map.bounds))`

How can I unravel all my 250000 tuples automatcally to feed it to such functions. In other words, how to not have parantethis but still have two number near each other and separated by comma?

Comment: Try using splat operator. Specifically, if `t = (29.1, 35.6)` then `LLA(t...)` will be `LLA(29.1, 35.6)`

Answer (score 1):

Hi I am unable to load the OpenStreetMaps package for some reason it says it is not registered...

But as far as I understand you need to first transform each individual tuple of latitudes and longitudes to LLA. I would just define a new method for the LLA function.
I don't know which package ultimately exports the LLA function/struct. Hence instead of defining a new method for it I just give the function a different name.

```
function LLA2(x::Tuple{Float64,Float64})
   return LLA(x[1],x[2])
end
```

Using this LLA2 function you can then just brodcast over your vector.

```
your_vector_LLA = LLA2.(your_vector)
```

Next you need to transform to ENU. According to the docs the function has two inputs. ENU(nodesLLA, lla_reference). I am assuming that maps.bounds is the lla_reference. You can then just broadcast over the LLA vector.

```
your_vector_ENU = ENU.(your_vector_LLA, (map.bounds,))
```

Unfortunately I can not help you further because I cannot add the package as mentioned earlier and I cannot find a nearest_node function only a nearestNode function in the OpenStreetMap docs.

Comment: Thanks @eohne  it gives ERROR: UndefVarError: Geodesy not defined

Comment: Hi @Rainbow since I dont know which package exports LLA just rename the function to LLA2 for now (function LLA2(x::Tuple{Float64,Float64}). Then use LLA2.(your_vector) subsequently. I have updated the answer accordingly.